# List of items sortable and save in order in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Lets suppose I have a table called shopping_items and every shopping item belongs to one id(person who owns the shopping items)

```
ID | ID_PERSON | ITEM | POSITION
1  | 10        | test | 3
1  | 10        | tes2 | 2
1  | 21        | tes3 | 3
1  | 10        | tes4 | 8
1  | 10        | tes5 | 10
```

On a page, I'll have a SORTABLE jquery that shows the items from the person 10 in the order of positions, but I want this to be dynamic and each alteration on the sort need to be saved.

Whats the best way to store this kinda data and make the sortable thing work?

Comment: may help https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=save+sortable+to+database

Comment: Have you ever used datatables? https://www.datatables.net/